# Bin directory in Linux -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash

Tags: command-line, bash

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash
```

what does this line mean. I found it in the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a line of the output of `ls -l`. A command which is used to list directory contents and display some additional information (run `man ls` for more info about how to use the command).

What the fields mean:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    -> permissions: read,write,execute for owner; read and execute for group and other users
1             -> 1 hardlink
root root     -> file is owned by user "root" in group "root"
920788        -> file is 920 KB large
Mar 28 2013   -> file was created on March 28 2013
bash          -> file is called bash
```